# Old receipt information is retrieved for in app purchases for test users

Tags: testing, in-app-purchase, subscription, storekit

I am using Auto-renewable subscriptions on my app and I am using sandbox users to test it with and for the first time purchase of an auto-renewable product in the app, its working fine, and the product gets renewed for the 6 times successfully (auto-renewable subscriptions renew up to five times after the initial purchase for a test environment).

It's failing for the next subscription-like if we do subscribe to a subscription that has got expired(after 6 times of successful renewal of that subscription), a react-native-iap (In-App-Purchase) library is returning an incorrect receipt that is the old successful subscription's transaction receipt.

Maybe it's a cache issue, but I'm not sure how to clean the cache or something like that.

Any suggestion or solution will be highly appreciated..Thanks.